Accessing a method of the parent class, from a sub-class in c#
Im getting myself twisted up in a knot, trying to access a method in a parent class, from inside a child class. My aproach/understanding of how this works I think is off.
The entry of my application looks a bit like this:
class my_app
{
  public static void Main(string[] args){

    core_functionality = new Core_functionality();
    core_functionality.start()
    // ...
    core_functionality.stop()
  }
}

then the core of my app lives in this class:
public class Core_functionality {

  private Sub_functionality sub_functionality; // does some other stuff underneath this class.

  public Core_functionality(){ 
    //constructor, initialises the sub class.
    sub_functionality = new Sub_functionality();
  }

  public do_a() {
    // do stuff here
    sub_functionality.do_stuff() 
  }

  public do_b(){
    // do other stuff here
  }
}

then finally inside my Sub_functionality class, i want to call do_a() in its parent core_functionality that initiated and started it..
public class Sub_functionality
{

  public class do_stuff() {
   
    // Somehow call Core_functionality.do_a() in here....

  }
}

im a bit lost on how to do this.  Visual studio will not let me access core_functionality.stop(), inside the sub_functionality class.
If I do  public class Sub_functionality : Core_functionality so it inherits, i get a constant loop in the output window that calls the constructor and finally gives up with a stackOverFlowException.
Pointers welcome on what im doing wrong here. Thankyou.

"i want to call do_a() in its parent core_functionality that initiated and started it" - why? If you need input from the callsite, define some parameters for Sub_functionality.do_stuff() ...

"finally inside my Sub_functionality class, i want to call do_a() in its parent core_functionality that initiated and started it.." why would you want an endless recursion ?

You seems to struggle with the difference of Inheritance (is-a) and Composition (has-a). It might be helpful to google it. This shouldn't be an RTFM comment its just that there are a gazillion sources that try to explain that and i am incompetent at finding one that is beginner level understandable.

Your naming is really hard to understand. Your current appraoch has no "parent" notion as in an inheritance-mechanics. Furthermore you seem to focus on a more functional approach where func1 calls into func2. The core of OOP however is about obbjects and their relationships. Having said this, it's hard to give any suggestion because we have no idea why you want SubFunction to call into CoreFunction. Usually when SubFunction returns , it'll automatically call into its caller, which is CoreFunction.

Java nested classes have an implicit ParentClass.this reference. C# does not. If you need a reference you must pass one into a contructor / argument / field. But it sounds like your design is backwards. Dependencies should work in one direction.


If I do public class Sub_functionality : Core_functionality so it
inherits, i get a constant loop in the output window that calls the
constructor and finally gives up with a stackOverFlowException.

This is because this:
  public Core_functionality(){ 
    //constructor, initialises the sub class.
    sub_functionality = new Sub_functionality();
  }

is inherited by Sub_functionality as its parameterless constructor. So the constructor is calling itself.
I think you are confusing composition and inheritance. You probably need to figure out which you want to use.
If Sub_functionality inherits from Core_Functionality, then it will be able to call non-private methods from Core_Functionality. If Sub_funtionality does not inherit from Core_Functionality, then it would need a reference to a Core_functionality object to be able to call its non-static methods.
One way of passing a Core_functionality reference to Sub_functionality is via its constructor:
public class Sub_functionality
{
    private readonly Core_functionality _coreFunctionality;

    public Sub_functionality(Core_functionality coreFunctionality)
    {
        _coreFunctionality = coreFunctionality;
    }
    //...
}


  public Core_functionality(){ 
    //constructor, initialises the sub class.
    sub_functionality = new Sub_functionality(this);
  }


Thankyou. I think what I want to do, is pass a reference into sub_functionality. Im just trying to understand how to do that.

@Toby I added an example of how you can do that.

I worked out the answer to my problem.
In my top level my_app class, i needed to define my core_functionality class as a public object. Like so...
class my_app
{

  public static Core_functionality core_functionality; // <--- Here

  public static void Main(string[] args){

    core_functionality = new Core_functionality();
    core_functionality.start()
    // ...
    core_functionality.stop()
  }
}

now i can do my_app.core_functionality.do_a(); elswhere in my other classes.
I hope this helps someone out there.
